# Webpack Module Federation Error ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed

Tags: webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

[image: My host is throwing this error.]

[image]

NOTE: I tried accessing this directly in the browser *https://localhost:5007/accom-web/dist/js/assets/browser-bundle/remoteEntryTest.js* and I'm served the remoteEntryTest.js file.

This is my webconfig in host.

[image]

This is webconfig of remote application.

[image]

Optimization config for remote application is below.

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
    emitOnErrors: true,
    splitChunks: {
       minSize: 256000,
       minChunks: 1,
       maxAsyncRequests: 10,
       automaticNameDelimiter: '-',
       cacheGroups: {
           chunks: 'initial',
           .....
       },
    },
    .....
}
```

I looked at the GitHub issues regarding this too but didn't help much.

https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/issues/307
https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/issues/1273
https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/issues/692

Any suggestions on this how to fix it?

Comment: any solution for this error ?

Comment: same issue, any solution for this error please?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with specifying shared dependencies on a remote. I ended up having to disable splitChucks after reviewing your Github references. I'm sure you tried that as well but this got my remote working again recently.

```
optimization: {
        splitChunks: false,
    },
```

Comment: hi @jaskru  where to add optimization

Comment: @GopinathKaliappan Inside webpack config.

Comment: What if need both SplitChunks as well as Remote??

Comment: What about Vite?, it doesn't have that option.

Comment: @xzegga did you find solution for vite?

Comment: Tried this does not work. Webpack 5.18. ReactJS.