# Webpack Shared module is not available for eager consumption: webpack/sharing/consume/default/react/react

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

```
Uncaught Error: Shared module is not available for eager consumption: webpack/sharing/consume/default/react/react
    at __webpack_require__.m.<computed> (consumes:148:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/index.js (Skills.js:44:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1
```

Getting this error when trying to lazy load my remote to my app. I used @craco/craco to edit my webconfig file.

This is what I have for my remote's craco config:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack").container.ModuleFederationPlugin;

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: "calculator",
          filename: "remoteEntry.js",
          exposes: {
            "./Calculator": "./src/App",  
          },
          shared: {
            react: { 
              singleton: true,
            },
            "react-dom": { 
              singleton: true
            },
            "antd": {
              singleton: true
            }
          },          
        })
      );
      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

and in my main app:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack").container.ModuleFederationPlugin;

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: "portfolio",
          remotes: {
            calculator: "calculator@https://pemdas-if107354y-emms21.vercel.app/remoteEntry.js",
          },
          shared: {
            react: { 
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: '^18.2.0'
            },
            "react-dom": { 
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: '^18.2.0'
            },
            "antd": {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: '^5.8.6'
            }
          },          
        })
      );

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

Not sure how much this matters, but I am running my main app locally.

FYI: I have tried delaying the initialization of the remote app by making the bootstrapping of the application asynchronous and lazy loading it in my app

Read through a few some what similar questions:
[Webpack Module Federation Error ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72450607/webpack-module-federation-error-scriptexternalloaderror-loading-script-failed)
[Webpack module federation is not working with eager shared libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123283/webpack-module-federation-is-not-working-with-eager-shared-libs?rq=3)